# lucene bypass parser for search?

Tags: lucene.net

I dont think its needed but i was curious

instead of generating a query string and searching lucene with it (ex "tag: abc 123 id:(2 or 99 or 123)") could i build a struct/class and pass it in?

using lucene.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean using directly the query API?

If yes take a look at `BooleanQuery`: http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_3/api/core/index.html

If you look in the `Lucene.Net.Search` namespace you will find a lot of query classes, and then you use the BooleanQuery class to combine them

```
BooleanQuery mainQuery = new BooleanQuery();
// add terms to the query
mainQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("tag", "abc")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
mainQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("tag", "123")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

// for the parentheses, do a sub BooleanQuery
BooleanQuery idQuery = new BooleanQuery();
idQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("id", "2")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
idQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("id", "99")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
idQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("id", "123")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

// append subquery to the main
mainQuery.Add(idQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

Then pass the `mainQuery` object to one of the `Searcher`'s method that takes a query in parameter.